Is the absolute value of an eigenfunction again an eigenfunction?
Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be open. Suppose $u : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^2$ function satisfying $-\Delta u = \lambda u$ for some $\lambda \ge 0$. I would like to show that $|u|$ also belongs to $C^2(\Omega)$ and that $-\Delta |u| = \lambda |u|$.
It is clear that the desired smoothness and equality holds in a neighborhood of any point $x$ at which $u(x) > 0$ or $u(x) < 0$. The problem is what to do near a point $x$ where $u(x) = 0$.
Some thoughts: integrating $|u|$ against $\partial_j \phi$, where $\phi \in C^\infty_0(\Omega)$, and using $|u| = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\sqrt{u^2 + \varepsilon}$ and the dominated convergence theorem, we do get that the distributional gradient of $|u|$ is $\textrm{sgn}(u)\nabla u$.
Edit: The assertion is not true in the generality stated above. As noted in the comments below and in an answer, there are counterexamples for $\lambda  = 0$, and for $\lambda > 0$ which is not the smallest eigenvalue associated to the Laplacian (with a certain boundary condition) on $\Omega$.
As also noted in the comments to an below, the assertion does seem to be true in some situations when one is dealing with the bottom of the spectrum. See another answer below for an indication about how this works.

For $\lambda=0$ this is surely not true, take for instance $(x,y)\mapsto x$.

Do you really want $|u| \in C^2(\Omega)$? I am probably missing something but if I take $\Omega=\mathbb R^2$ and $\lambda=0$ then $u = x_1$ is an example, since $\Delta(u) = (\partial_1^2+\partial_2^2)(x_1)=0$, but $|x_1|$ is not $\mathcal C^1$ on ${(x_1,x_2): x_1=0}$.

This is not true for $\lambda>0$: Take $n=1$ and $\Omega$ to be interval $[0,\pi]$, with the Dirichlet boundary condition that the functions vanish at the end-points. Then the spectrum of $\Delta$ is discrete with eigenfunctions $u_k(t)=\sin(kt)$ and eigenvalues $\{k^2: k \in \mathbb Z_{>0}\}$ (i.e. $(-\Delta+\lambda_n)(u_n)=0$ where $\lambda_k = k^2$). Clearly in this case $|\sin(kt)|$ is not a $\mathcal C^2$ eigenfunction for $k \geq 2$, so there is a problem with the case $n=1$.
This propagates to all $n \geq 1$ if you allow me to take $\Omega$ to be a "cube" (cuboid?) of the form $[0,\pi]^n$ with vanishing Dirichlet boundary conditions.

Thank you for your answer. I'm having trouble reconciling the work here with Victor Ivrii's note https://www.math.utoronto.ca/ivrii/PDE-textbook/Chapter13/S13.3.html. Showing that $|u|$ is an eigenfunction is a key step in the argument that the first Dirichlet eigenfunction is simple and each eigenfunction has a fixed sign.

I think the point there is that you can characterize the eigenspace for the lowest eigenvalue by the variational problem of minimizing $Q(u)$ on the space $L^2(\Omega)$. Since $|u|$ is certainly still $L^2$ and has $Q(u)=Q(|u|)$ it follows $|u|$ must also be an eigenfunction.

@JZS it's only true for the eigenfunction with the lowest eigenvalue. It's not true for other eigenfunctions.

Let $A$ be a semibounded, possibly unbounded self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $H$. For $f$ a Borel function, use $f(A)$ to denote the operator associated to $A$, as supplied by the spectral theorem. Let $\varphi$ be an element of the quadratic form domain of $A$ (i.e., $\varphi$ belongs to the domain of $|A|^{1/2}$), and suppose $\| \varphi \|  = 1$. The measure associated to $\varphi$ by the spectral theorem is
\begin{equation*}
\begin{gathered}
\mu_\varphi (E) = \langle \varphi, \mathbf{1}_{E} (A) \varphi \rangle, \qquad E \subseteq \mathbb{R}, \\
\mu_\varphi(\mathbb{R}) = \mu_\varphi(\mathbb{R} \cap [\inf \sigma(A), \infty)) = \| \varphi \|^2 = 1,
\end{gathered}
\end{equation*}
where $\mathbf{1}_E$ denotes an indicator function. Suppose further that
\begin{equation*}
 \int_{[\inf \sigma(A), \infty)} \lambda d\mu_\varphi = \inf \sigma(A).
\end{equation*}
Then it is the case that $\inf \sigma(A)$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, $\varphi$ belongs to the domain of $A$, and $A \varphi = \inf \sigma (A) \varphi$.
The way to see this is to simply note that if $\mu_\varphi((\inf\sigma(A) + \varepsilon, \infty)) >  0$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$, then
\begin{equation*}
\inf \sigma(A) = \inf \sigma(A) \int_{[\inf \sigma(A), \infty)} d\mu_\varphi < \int_{[\inf \sigma(A), \infty)} \lambda d\mu_\varphi = \inf \sigma(A),
 \end{equation*}
which is a contradiction. Hence $\|\varphi \|^2 = \mu_\varphi(\{\inf \sigma(A)\}) = \|\mathbf{1}_{\{ \inf \sigma(A)\}}(A) \varphi \|^2$. That is, $\varphi$ belongs to the range of $\mathbf{1}_{\{ \inf \sigma(A)\}}(A)$, and is thus an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\inf \sigma(A)$.
